# max_input_time value is -1 is this normal?

Tags: wordpress, server

In WordPress I see this while using a debug plugin: max_input_time -1
Is this normal or must I increase it? 
I do see this on some of my client's sites and I don't really know what it means.
Any thoughts? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the default value for that Constant in php.

http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php

For the documentation it says:

> This sets the maximum time in seconds a script is allowed to parse input data, like POST and GET. Timing begins at the moment PHP is invoked at the server and ends when execution begins. The default setting is -1, which means that max_execution_time is used instead. Set to 0 to allow unlimited time.